# FlatList's renderItem doesn't recognise "this" keyword

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

So, I recently started making FlatList a recurring thing in the app I'm working on. I am right now working on a screen that gives a list of requests and is updated once one is accepted, which is done by pressing a button. There's a method called getNewRequests I am using to update the requests, but it can't seem to be called by the flatline, as it only returns the error `TypeError: _this3 is undefined`.

I really need that method to work, because I need to update the state of that screen, and trying to type the whole method there only returns the same error. In that context, `this` always returns `undefined`.

```
render(){
    return(
      <View style={GenericStyles.styles.genericContainer}>
        <Text> REQUEST SCREEN </Text>

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.requestList}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />

        <Button title="Voltar" color="cyan" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}/>
      </View>
    );
  }

renderItem({item}){
    return(
      <Card
        containerStyle={{flex: 1, width: 200}}
        title={item.Username}>
          <Button color="blue" title="Accept" onPress={() => RequestService.allowRequest(item.id, (response) => {
            let rsp = JSON.parse(response);

            if(rsp.success){
              this.getNewRequests();
            }

          })}/>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either bind the function in your constructor (or wherever you want) doing:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.renderItem.bind(this)
}
```

or use arrow function:

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    //your function
}
```

Doing this will give the function access to the `this` of the current component.

Comment: Using the arrow function worked, thanks! Would you mind explaining why a normal method doesn't work but an arrow function does?